# I am using node.js and stdin, but the program ends before the user can input their binary to be evaluated

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node.js and stdin, but the program ends before the user can input their binary to be evaluated.

```
let stdin = process.stdin;
process.addListener("data", function(l) {
  let input = l.toString().trim();

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("You entered"+"["+input+"]"+"Calculating...")
   }, 100);

   console.log(parseInt(input, 2));

});
```

Comment: just define some input dear

Comment: `stdin.addListener()`

Comment: thanks :) If you cant tell -- I am new to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `addListener` on `stdin` you declared on first line, like this:

```
let stdin = process.stdin;
stdin.addListener("data", function(l) {
  let input = l.toString().trim();

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("You entered"+"["+input+"]"+"Calculating...")
  }, 100);

  console.log(parseInt(input, 2));
});
```